# objective-c how to modify button text of a button different than the button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

This is what I would use to change the text if it were the same method but I want to change it from a different method.

```
-(IBAction)StartTimer:(id)sender {
     [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
-(IBAction)ResetAllData:(id)sender {
      [(NEED THIS PIECE) setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: You probably already have an IBOutlet for the other button.  Use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it. Perhaps the simplest one is to make an `IBOutlet` for the other button, give it a name (say, `anotherButton`), attach it in the storyboard, and call it directly, like this:

```
-(IBAction)ResetAllData:(id)sender {
      [anotherButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

An alternative would be to add a tag <sup>*</sup> to the button in question (say, 123), and then reference it by its numeric tag, like this:

```
-(IBAction)ResetAllData:(id)sender {
      [[self viewWithTag:123] setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

<sup>*</sup> To add a tag, select the button in the interface builder, open its properties, find the tag, and type in the desired value in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `UIButton` you want to change the title of a property of the class, then you will have direct access to it. For example, the following could be put in your `ViewController`'s `.m` file.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UIButton *otherButton;
@end
```

Then in your first `IBAction`, just set the title of `otherButton`.

```
-(IBAction)ResetAllData:(id)sender {
      [self.otherButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```